# Were the "maidens" of Rebekah "schifchot" to Isaac or "pileg'shim" to Isaac?

Tags: marriage, slave-serve-eved-avadim, imahot-matriarch-mothers, concubine

Were all or one of the "maidens" of Rebekah "schifchot" to Isaac or "pileg'shim" to Isaac (regardless whether he consummated with them or not)? Why or why not?

The "maiden" of Sarah was a shifcha or pilegesh to Abraham.
Likewise both the maidens of Rachel and Leah were shifchot or pilegshim to Israel.

Rebekah's maidens are found in [Bereishit 24:61](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.61?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

What do our authorities say?

Comment: The Tora does not tell us that the maidens of Rebekah interact with Isaac, unlike Hagar, Zilpa and Bilhah. Not all maiden are promoted to concubines....

Comment: @AlaychemgoestoCodidact I understand that "The Tora does not tell us", and that is why I asked, "What do our authorities say?"

Comment: The Torah does not even suggest a relationship between  Rebekah's maidens and Isaac. The commentaries quoted by Sefaria to the possuk do not mention it either.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It does not have to. There is, however, precedent, that the maidens, or one of them, can serve as a shifcha or pilegesh to Isaac. Hence, I want to know if any authorities, pre-rabbinic or rabbinic, had also thought or taught otherwise.

Comment: @ninamag I'm saying, that the Tora is not "shy" and hide this kind of details from us, as we see with Avraham and Yaakov, so why saying it otherwise with Issac?

Answer (score 1):

[Yeshiva.org.il has an article on יצחק אבינו](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95)

> כאשר הכתוב מספר כי יצחק אבינו לקח את רבקה כאשר היה בן ששים שנה, רש"י
> מבאר זאת ומוסיף ליצחק את הכינוי התואם את תכונותיו:"בן שישים שנה - עשר
> שנים משנשאה עד שנעשית בת שלוש עשרה שנה וראויה להריון, ועשר שנים הללו
> צפה והמתין לה כמו שעשה אביו לשרה, כיון שלא נתעברה ידע שהיא עקרה והתפלל
> עליה. ושפחה לא רצה לישא, לפי שנתקדש בהר המוריה להיות עולה תמימה.
>
> It explains according to Rashi that Isaac was 60 years old when he married Rebecca who
> was 3 years old. Isaac waited 10 years until she was 13 and should be
> able to conceive and then waited another 10 years for her to conceive.
> She did not conceive. (*Avrohom took a shifcho after the 10 years that
> he waited for Soroh to conceive.*) Isaac did not want to to take a
> shifcho because he was made holy as an עולה תמימה (perfect offering)
> when he was taken up on Mount Moriah (*and it would have been
> inappropriate for the  עולה תמימה to associate with a shifcho.*)

So we see that Isaac had no other partners and therefore did not associate with Rebecca's maidens.